# SVG image not found in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

I have an issue with displaying images in Rails. I've got two images (bluedot.svg and reddot.svg). The bluedot.svg will show on the website. The reddot.svg is not shown on the website. I'm trying to display the dots as markers on a google map. Here is my code.

For the Blue marker:

```
var iconBlue = {
   url: "<%= image_path('bluedot.svg') %>", // url
   scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(80, 70), // scaled size
   origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
   anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0) // anchor
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,
   position: geolocate,
   icon: iconBlue,
   animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
   title: "Current Location",
   html:
     '<div class=MarkerPop>' +
      '<p>Latitude: '+ position.coords.latitude + '</p>' +
      '<p>Longitude: '+ position.coords.longitude + '</p>'
});
```

For the Red marker:

```
var iconRed = {
  url: "<%= image_path('reddot.svg') %>", // url
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(80, 70), // scaled size
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0) // anchor
};

$.each(locationId, function () {
  myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locationLat[counter], locationLng[counter]);
  clearMarkers();
  allMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatlng,
     map: map,
     icon: iconRed,
     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
     title: locationName[counter],
     html:
           '<div class=MarkerPop>' +
            '<h1>' + locationName[counter] + '<h1>' +
            '<h3>' + locationAddress[counter] + '<h3>' +
            '<p>' + locationComment[counter] + '</p>' +
           '<div>'
   })
);
```

The images are identical only the fill color are different. They are both in the same folder.

I've tried to precompile the images but this didn't help either.

```
rake assets:precompile
```

I've tried to delete the temp/cache/assets folder and the public/assets folder and restart the server but this didn't help.

I've changed the javascript file extension from map.js to map.js.erb. This helped but didn't display the image.

The error that I'm getting in Google Chrome console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/images/reddot.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

The error that I'm getting in the Rails server console:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/reddot.svg")
```

Does anybody have an idea what next to do?

Comment: Can you navigate both urls and see/ get the images? And what shows up if you run 'rake routes'?

Comment: I figured it out and it was a bit silly. In the file explorer I couldn't see a space between in the reddot.svg file name. It was named "reddot .svg". Once I went to the console and viewed the image name I saw the error. Thanks though @rik for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and it was a bit silly. In the file explorer I couldn't see a space between in the reddot.svg file name. It was named "reddot .svg". Once I went to the console and viewed the image name I saw the error. Thanks though @rik for your help!